# How to remove any kind of selectable fields in PDF

Tags: pdf

I am trying to remove these selectable fields from this PDF. The goal is to remove them and then run them through an OCR so that I make a searchable PDF. I have managed to make the PDF searchable already, but then I get horizontal lines that came there because of these selectable fields in the original PDF. Does someone know how to remove these fields?

I have tried flattening the PDF online, it didn't remove these fields.

I tried to convert the PDF to Djvu, and then back to PDF. It did get rid of the selectable fields, but the PDF file size became 10 times larger and I couldn't use the online OCR anymore. I tried to compress that PDF but the quality was drastically reduced.

[image: The selectable fields I want to remove.]

Comment: Have you tried printing he PDF as a PDF, e.g. using Windows or Firefox's "Print as PDF" choice as printer?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I tried to go Print->Save as PDF in Firefox and Chrome, but it didn't work, in both cases, I again have the lines and these selectable boxes on my PDF. It's interesting that when I open the PDF using Chrome I don't see the boxes, but in Firefox I do see. In both cases, the boxes exist in the PDF.